# Ошибка обновления Laravel,

Tags: laravel

Обновляю фреймворк по гайду, но получаю ошибку. Подскажите, в какую сторону думать хотя бы.

- don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v
  3.23
- don't install laravel/framework 7.x-dev|don't install illuminate/support v
  3.4
- Installation request for laravel/framework ^7.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/
  amework[7.x-dev, v7.0.0, v7.0.1, v7.0.2, v7.0.3, v7.0.4, v7.0.5, v7.0.6, v7.0.

Comment: по какому гайду, до какой версии и море других вопросов...

Comment: вы где-то накосячили с версиями зависимостей в компосере.. смотрите их.